Optimal implementation of storing single strings in postgresql for search speed
I have a database that will have 1m+ records of the following shape:
create table simplified(
    url text primary key,   -- google.com/search?=something
    url_host text not null, -- google.com
    url_path text not null  -- /search?=something 
)

I understand that to search for a urls substr a simple query could be:
select * from simplified where url like '%google%'

I am trying to optimize for speed of search and am willing to form the data in anyway. Some questions I have:

Is the LIKE operator really what I want for speed? or is there a faster alternative?
Can tsvector or tsquery be implemented with a GIN index in a meaningful way for single string search?
If not #2 is there something similar?

Thank you for your time in advance.
I have tried tsvector implementations to no avail, and some research on the topic.

Depends. Are you searching for whole words or word stems, or any substring?

That table structure is terrible. First, I recommend using varchar(900) instead if text, because you get an error with very long strings in a B-tree index. Perhaps an artificial primary key would be better? The URLs might change... Second, don't store the parts redundantly, but use a view to calculate them on the fly.

Check the pg_trgm extension, that supports similarity searches using LIKE, ILIKE and (some) regexes.
